# Wordpress: How can show all Contributors' Posts

Tags: wordpress

When Contributor add new post in my site, and i approve it,

The problem is when any user click in Contributor name to show all post of this Contributors. Its show me 404 error.

So i need way to show all Contributors' Posts in online page.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme doesn't have an [Author Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates), and that is why you are receiving the 404 error.

To list all of the posts of that author, use this snippet:

```
<p>Written by: 
<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></p>
```

And save it as `author.php` in the theme folder.

Or, better yet, as a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: i have, all role=author is show all posts for him, but all role=contributor not show me posts of him

Comment: If you could post the content of the `author.php` file, it would be easier to assist you

Comment: i am use genesis framework and its not have author.php

Comment: This is the reason you get a 404 error, if you save the code snippet I wrote as `author.php`, the problem would be solved

Comment: but other author its open